# Capital city with two clues

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, geography, movies, sports

**Bamako**

1. Cassius Marcellus Clay Jr.
2. Mahershalalhashbaz Gilmore.

---

**La Paz** and **Sucre**

1. Academy Award recipient for 'To Each His Own'.
2. Academy Award recipient for 'The Favourite'.

---

**Athens**

1. A football player for Chelsea FC.
2. A cricket player for England national team.

---

**X**

1. A fictional character in the Marvel Cinematic Universe.
2. A 1988 heist comedy film.

---

***Identify the capital city X.***

Comment: I hate puzzles based on trivia.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> X = Kigali

All hints point to countries missing their first letters:

**Bamako**

> Muhammad **Ali** and Mahershala **Ali** -> MALI

**La Paz and Sucre**

> **Olivia** de Havilland and **Olivia** Colman -> BOLIVIA

**Athens**

> **Reece** James and **Reece** Topley -> GREECE

**X**

> **Wanda** Maximoff and A fish called **Wanda** -> RWANDA